# casting void* pointer back with shared_pointer as instance variable

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a class like this

```
Class Bar {
  void doSomething() {}
}

Class Foo {
   std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar() {
      return bar_;
   };
   void methodInFoo() {
   }
private::
   std::shared_ptr <Bar> bar_
}
```

There is a callback that takes void * pointer

```
callback(void *) {

}
```

and an object of type Foo is passed to it

```
Foo foo = makeFoo();

callback(&foo);
```

Now inside of callback i need to access B

```
callback(void * data) {
   Foo* foo = static_cast<Foo *> data; // works fine
   foo->methodInFoo(); // no error
   auto bar = foo->bar() // seems to work
   bar -> doSomething() // leads to a Segmentation fault 

}
```

Accessing anything inside of shared pointer leads to a segmentation fault

but if i pass pointer to bar to callback it works fine

for example:

```
Foo *foo = getFoo()

callback(foo->bar().get()) //pass pointer to bar

callback(void* data) {
  Bar* bar = static_cast<Bar*>(data);
  bar->doSomething() // works fine
}
```

So my question is if i static cast a pointer to object which has shared_ptr as instance variable to another object, does accessing that shared pointer after cast leads to undefined behavior or should it work fine

Am I missing something

Comment: Just to double-check: should this line: `Bar * bar = foo->bar().get()` actually be `Bar * bar = foo->bar()->something()` ?

Comment: How did `Foo` get converted to `void*` in `callback(foo)` call? Is `foo` actually a `Foo*`? Show a [mcve]. My educated guess is that you are passing around dangling pointers, long after the `Foo` object has been destroyed.

Comment: It’s hard to write an answer because your code snippets aren’t valid C++. Important details may be missing. Please edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, please clarify what *exactly* you mean by “does not work”.

Comment: specifically one part that looks funky likely should be callback(&foo);

Comment: updated question a bit more , hope it clearer , really if i static_cast to an object that has shared_pointer instance variable , accessing any method on that shared  pointer leads to segmentaton fault after cast

Comment: My guess is that `foo` has been destroyed by the time the callback runs, so you are using an object after it has been destroyed.

Comment: In  your example, `Foo` isn't initializing `baz_` - the default constructor of `std::shared_ptr<T>` does not construct an instance, it just sets the pointer to null. Can you provide a _viable_ minimal sample to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Also: are you 99% sure you need a `shared_ptr<T>`? I have worked on several large codebases and unless you really need to do something super complex you can generally get away with `std::unique_ptr<T>` and a good usage of move semantics. As a rule of thumb, always start with a `std::unique_ptr<T>` and then swap in a shared pointer only if there's no other way to do something safely and properly - shared pointers use atomic operations, so they can kinda tank performance if used improperly.

Comment: @at_123: Please show a working example (one that actually crashes), including the code for `Foo`, `Bar`, and the like.

Comment: I miss the good old days when there was only one "cast" operator and no such thing as shared pointers or unique_ptr<>